# S-Docs - How to rotate text

Tags: html, pdf, html-table, salesforce

I have create an sample template on S-Docs (Salesforce App).
I want to create a table with a columns are in vertical like in this image
[image]

This is my template html:

```
<style>
div.vertical
{
 margin-left: -85px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 215px;
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Safari/Chrome */
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Opera */
 -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
}

td.vertical
{
 height: 220px;
 line-height: 14px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 text-align: left;
}
</style>    
<table border="1">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="vertical">
            <div class="vertical">Really long and complex title 1</div>
            </td>
            <td class="vertical">
            <div class="vertical">Really long and complex title 2</div>
            </td>
            <td class="vertical">
            <div class="vertical">Really long and complex title 3</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p class="rotate">TESTING</p>

            <p>Exaoppomple</p>
            </td>
            <td>a, b, c</td>
            <td>1, 2, 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And when I click on Preview template then it appear like this
[image]

Please help.

**Update:** It's look like Save and Preview in S-Docs does not support rotate text. I have try to add background color for a class and the background color is working but the rotate does not work when preview or when generate PDF file. Rotate only viewable when in Edit mode of S-Docs.

Answer (score 1):

You should focus on the element of the table, not on the whole table.
So, the code will come out as show as below:

```
<table border="1">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="vertical">
            <div class="vertical">Really long and complex title 1</div>
            </td>
            <td class="vertical">
            <div class="vertical">Really long and complex title 2</div>
            </td>
            <td class="vertical">
            <div class="vertical">Really long and complex title 3</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p class="rotate">TESTING</p>

            <p class="exaoppomple">Exaoppomple</p>
            </td>
            <td>a, b, c</td>
            <td>1, 2, 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<style>
{
 margin-left: -85px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 215px;
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Safari/Chrome */
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Opera */
 -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
}

td.vertical
{
 height: 220px;
 line-height: 14px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 text-align: left;
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.rotate{
  margin-top: 120px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.exaoppomple{
  margin-right: 50px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
</style>
```

you can refer to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Halu/qx1t50zv/2/)

Comment: Thank for your quick response , but unfortunately it does not work.
Text on table does not rotate

Comment: please refer to my fiddle, is it not work for you?

Comment: the fiddle working just fine, I try my original code on fiddle as well and it working just fine. It's only failed when I preview this as PDF file

Comment: So, you want to try to rotate each element of the PDF file?

Comment: I want to rotate <td> element in table from horizontal to vertical like the first Image in my question

Comment: It's working just fine on html but when preview it on PDF then it does not show <td> as vertical. I'm not sure what's wrong about it when preview it in S-Docs

Comment: I found out the customizing table solution of [S-DOC official document](https://www.sdocs.com/resources/documentation/customizing-your-related-list-layout/), since I can't see your code currently. I think you can refer to it's adjusted method and use devtool to select the target element to rotate what you want